# Search All databases for stored procedures for SQL

Tags: database, stored-procedures

What am I missing to get perform a query on all databases to search to see if a SP exist on all databases?

This is what i'm using:

SP_MSForEachDb 'SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = "P" AND name = "'usp_perfnon_tokals'"
IF name('usp_perfnon_tokals') is not null
    PRINT 'Present!'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Not accounted for'

Answer (score 0):

You can use information_schema

```
select * 
  from information_schema.routines 
 where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

This query return all the stored procedures in all your schemas
you can narrow it down by adding a more conditions in the where clause something like

```
select * 
  from information_schema.routines 
 where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
and SPECIFIC_NAME like '%Name%'
```